# Choosing type based on lambda signature

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, template-meta-programming

I am trying to determine a type based on the signature of a lambda expression.

I've come up with the following code, which works, but I'm wondering if there isn't a simpler way to go about it. I've posted [a full working example on ideone](http://ideone.com/ZWBHAM).

```
template <typename T_Callback>
class CallbackType {
private:
    template <typename T>
    static CallbackFunctionA<T> testlambda(void (T::*op)(A const &) const);
    template <typename T>
    static CallbackFunctionB<T> testlambda(void (T::*op)(B const &) const);

    template <typename T>
    static decltype(testlambda<T>(&T::operator())) testany(int);
    template <typename T>
    static T &testany(...);
public:
    typedef decltype(testany<T_Callback>(0)) type;
};
```

In short, `T_Callback` can be either:

- a lambda of the form `[](A const &) { }`
- a lambda of the form `[](B const &) { }`
- an instance of the class `Callback` or a class derived therefrom

It `T_Callback` is a lambda, a wrapper class derived from `Callback` should be returned (`CallbackFunctionA` or `CallbackFunctionB`), otherwise a reference to the callback type itself should be returned.

As I said the above code works just fine, but I'm wondering if it can be simplified, i.e. by removing the need for both `testany` and `testlambda` functions.

Comment: Why doesn't `std::function` work for you? Also, are you aware of generic lambdas?

Comment: @Deduplicator std::function doesn't work because I need to add placeholder operators that are not defined by the lambda. The wrapper calls the specified lambda instead of the placeholder when the lambda matches. See the example on ideone for details. I wasn't aware of generic lambdas, thanks. That might be an alternative in the future for defining a callback that can take both an `A` or a `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you say you want:

- a lambda of the form `[](A const &) { }` shall be mapped to `CallbackFuncionA`
- a lambda of the form `[](B const &) { }` shall be mapped to `CallbackFunctionB`
- an instance of the class Callback or a class derived therefrom shall be mapped to itself

What you actually have:

- A functor having exactly one `operator()` returning nothing and having one argument of type `const A&` will be mapped to `CallbackFunctionA`
- A functor having exactly one `operator()` returning nothing and having one argument of type `const B&` will be mapped to `CallbackFunctionB`
- Anything else will be mapped to itself

My suggestion: Define a simple forwarder like this, for invoking when possible:

```
template<class X, class ARG...>
static auto may_invoke(const X& x, ARG&&... arg)
-> decltype(x(std::forward<ARG>(arg)...))
{ return x(std::forward<ARG>(arg)...); }
struct not_invoked {};
template<class X>
constexpr static not_invoked may_invoke(const X&, ...)
{ return {}; }
```

Also, a tester whether it can be invoked is nice to have:

```
template<class X, class ARG...>
constexpr bool does_invoke(const X& x, ARG&&... arg)
{ return !std::is_same<not_invoked,
      decltype(may_invoke(x, std::forward<ARG>(arg)...))>::value; }
```

That allows you to at the same time make your code more general and the tests more stringent.

Comment: Great suggestion, thank you! At the moment this allows me to call my executor with anything (e.g. `may_invoke(0, ...)`), but I guess that's what the tester is for.

Answer (score 0):

According to your specs, you need:

1. one step to differentiate (lambda) classes with one defined member operator() from classes derived from Callback (that apparently are assumed not to have exactly one member operator()), for which usage of SFINAE is the appropriate technique (impl with `testany`).
2. and another step to differentiate between the different argument types (A and B) of the found member operator (impl with `testlamda`).

Combining these steps in one would require both accessing the operator() in the call to testany from typedef test as well as resolving if such member function exists, which seems impossible to me.