# Variadic Template Dispatcher

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

I would like to use variadic templates to help solve an issue using va-args.  Basically, I want to call a singular function, pass into the function a "command" along with a variable list of arguments, then dispatch the arguments to another function.

I've implemented this using tried and true (but not type safe) va_list.  Here's an attempt I made at doing this using variadic templates. The example doesn't compile below as you will quickly find out why...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef enum cmd_t
{
    CMD_ZERO,
    CMD_ONE,
    CMD_TWO,
} COMMANDS;


int cmd0(double a, double b, double c)
{
    cout << "cmd0  " << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << endl;
    return 0;
}

int cmd1(int a, int b, int c)
{
    cout << "cmd1  " << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << endl;
    return 1;
}

template<typename... Args>
int DispatchCommand(COMMANDS cmd, Args... args)
{
    int stat = 0;
    switch (cmd)
    {
    case CMD_ZERO:
        cmd0(args...);
        break;
    case CMD_ONE:
        cmd1(args...);
        break;
    default:
        stat = -1;
        break;
    }
    return stat;
}

int main()
{
    int stat;
    stat = DispatchCommand(CMD_ZERO, 1, 3.141, 4);
    stat = DispatchCommand(CMD_ONE, 5, 6, 7);
    stat = DispatchCommand(CMD_TWO, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I can modify this function to use variadic templates correctly?

Comment: Why don't you use plain old function overloading? Define a function `DispatchCommand` which takes 4 parameters, overload it with one that takes five and so on.

Comment: Is `COMMANDS cmd` known at compile time ?

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25264850

Comment: @Jarod42: It would have to be, to provide the right parameter types.  As such, this question makes no sense.  He's trying to "forget" which function he's going to use, and then deduce it again, and it can't be deduced properly.  The solution is to not forget the signature in the first place.

Comment: @ Jarod40 - Yes the COMMANDS enum is known at compile time

Comment: @dyp - This is a good solution, however, the one I have in mind will have literally 100s of overloads. I am looking for a better solution that would provide a single function interface that could be exported from a DLL for use by many clients...

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem: You already have 100s of overloads, `cmd0` to `cmd321`. Do you want to export a single function from the DLL to call any of them?

Answer (score 0):

Write some code that, given a function pointer and a set of arguments, calls it with the longest prefix of those arguments that works.

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
template<class types0, size_t N, class types1=types<>>
struct split;

template<class t00, class...t0s, size_t N, class...t1s>
struct split<types<t00,t0s...>,N,types<t1s...>>:
  split<types<t0s...>,N-1,types<t1s...,t00>>
{};
template<class...t0s, class...t1s>
struct split<types<t0s...>,0,types<t1s...>>
{
  using right=types<t0s...>;
  using left=types<t1s...>;
};
template<class>using void_t=void;
template<class Sig,class=void>
struct valid_call:std::false_type{};
template<class F, class...Args>
struct valid_call<F(Args...), void_t<
  decltype( std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...) )
>>:std::true_type {};

template<class R, class types>
struct prefix_call;

template<class R, class...Args>
struct prefix_call<R, types<Args...>> {
  template<class F, class... Extra>
  std::enable_if_t< valid_call<F(Args...)>::value, R >
  operator()(R default, F f, Args&&...args, Extra&&...) const
  {
    return std::forward<F>(f)(args...);
  }
  template<class F, class... Extra>
  std::enable_if_t< !valid_call<F(Args...)>::value, R >
  operator()(R default, F f, Args&&...args, Extra&&...) const
  {
    return prefix_call<R, typename split<types<Args...>, sizeof...(Args)-1>::left>{}(
      std::forward<R>(default), std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...
    );
  }
};

template<class R>
struct prefix_call<R, types<>> {
  template<class F, class... Extra>
  std::enable_if_t< valid_call<F()>::value, R >
  operator()(R default, F f, Extra&&...) const
  {
    return std::forward<F>(f)();
  }
  template<class F, class... Extra>
  std::enable_if_t< !valid_call<F()>::value, R >
  operator()(R default, F f, Extra&&...) const
  {
    return std::forward<R>(default);
  }
};
```

the above code may contain typos.

```
template<typename... Args>
int DispatchCommand(COMMANDS cmd, Args... args)
{
  int stat = 0;
  switch (cmd) {
    case CMD_ZERO: {
      stat = prefix_call<int, Args...>{}(-1, cmd0, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } break;
    case CMD_ONE: {
      stat = prefix_call<int, Args...>{}(-1, cmd1, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } break;
    default: {
      stat = -1;
    } break;
  }
  return stat;
}
```

If `cmd0` or `cmd1` is overridden, you'll have to use the overload set technique.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following:

```
template <COMMANDS cmd> struct command
{
    template <typename ... Args>
    int operator() (Args&&...) const { return -1; }
};

template <> struct command<CMD_ZERO>
{
    int operator()(double a, double b, double c) const
    {
        std::cout << "cmd0  " << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

template <> struct command<CMD_ONE>
{
    int operator()(int a, int b, int c) const
    {
        std::cout << "cmd1  " << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
};

template <COMMANDS cmd, typename... Args> int DispatchCommand(Args&&... args)
{
    return command<cmd>()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And then use it like:

```
DispatchCommand<CMD_ZERO>(1., 3.141, 4.);
DispatchCommand<CMD_ONE>(5, 6, 7);
DispatchCommand<CMD_TWO>(5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/eQsnLS)

But using directly the different functions seems simpler:

```
cmd0(1., 3.141, 4.);
cmd1(5, 6, 7);
```